# Add Styling to First Item in ListView XAML

Tags: c#, xaml

I have a ListView as such:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SourceItems}" Grid.Row="1">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1, 1, 0, 0">
                <Grid>
                    <Label Content="{Binding PropertyName}" FontSize="15"/>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

This listview sets up each row to have a Label and Checkbox as included above. What I want to do is add styling so that the first item in the listview has a different color background so that it distinguishes the start of the listview items.

I have tried adding this ItemContainerStyle, which works in changing the color of the first item, but it affects the styling of the borderbrush and checkbox alignment.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SourceItems}" Grid.Row="0">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1, 1, 0, 0">
                <Grid>
                    <Label Content="{Binding PropertyName}" FontSize="15"/>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource PreviousData}}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>              
</ListView>
```

Is there a way to change this xaml so that the Checkbox styling is as used in the DataTemplate?

Answer (score 0):

In your source Data "**SourceItems**" can you add a property

```
public Color BackgroundColorValue { get; set; }
```

And set it while the data is fetched from the source.

Then bind the background property directly

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SourceItems}" Grid.Row="1">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1, 1, 0, 0">
                <Grid Background={Binding BackgroundColorValue}>
                    <Label Content="{Binding PropertyName}" FontSize="15"/>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thank you! On an unrelated note, how could I go about removing the checkbox from the first item in the listview?